# Advice on mod_rewrite url in Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, rewrite, url

I'm trying to set up a `mod_rewrite` rule so that when the webpage `www.mysite.com/blog` is requested a page from the blogging service Tumblr is loaded. I have set up my Tumblr site so that blog.mysite.com returns the domain. Currently, `www.mysite.com/blog` redirects to `blog.mysite.com`. What I want is `www.mysite.com/blog` to display `blog.mysite.com` and for the user not to be aware of `blog.mysite.com`. I have tried several difference approaches to achieve this. First, I tried to use a rewrite rule:

```
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteRule  /blog/   http://blog.mysite.com/    [NC,P,L]
```

Then a 'ProxyPass' (attempt 1)

```
ProxyPass /blog/ http://blog.mysite.com/
```

and attempt 2:

```
<Location /blog/>
    ProxyPass http://blog.mysite.com/
</Location>
```

Then, I saw another more sophisticated `mod_rewrite` rule which I also tried:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite.com/blog$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/standard
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://blog.mysite.com$1   [R]
</IfModule>
```

I would appreciate any advice on how best to do this.

Comment: Can you clarify what the problems were with the proxying approach?

Comment: The url was not rewritten - it successfully redirected, but it was clear that the url had changed in the browser from `mysite.com/blog` to  `blog.mysite.com`

Comment: So you were proxying to `mysite.tumblr.com`, which was then redirecting to `blog.mysite.com`, is that correct?  Do you get redirected when you visit `mysite.tumblr.com` directly in your browser?  It sounds like this is caused by tumblr's handling of these requests, it might be completely out of your control.

Comment: Apologies, I just realized that I had got confused as I wrote the question. `blog.mysite.com` is fine, it's just the secret redirect between `mysite.com/blog` that I am trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention specific issues for each case, but in my experience the best thing to do, when trying to debug RewriteRules, is to turn on the rewrite  log and crank up the rewriteloglevel.  This will display the incoming request, and the pass/fail for each rule, as well as what it does with the request when it matches a rule.

```
RewriteLog "/usr/local/var/apache/logs/rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 3
```

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteloglevel

Remember to disable this once you've finished, as it does cause a performance hit, especially at 3 and above.

Answer (score 0):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite.com/blog$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/standard
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://blog.mysite.com$1   [R]
</IfModule>
```

That rule is almost correct, it should be:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite.com$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/standard
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://blog.mysite.com$1   [R]
</IfModule>
```

Try that.